# transfer HD video file by VLC and play it using g-streamer

Tags: gstreamer

Plase give me example of the command line on the server VLC and the command line on the client (g-streamer) protocols may be (udp,rtsp,rtp) but prefer rtsp

Answer (score 0):

For RTSP the examples is as follows :-

*Run on the server:

```
vlc -vvv input_stream --sout '#rtp{dst=192.168.0.12,port=1234,sdp=rtsp://server.example.org:8080/test.sdp}'
```

On the client:-

```
vlc rtsp://server.example.org:8080/test.sdp
```